# How to execute a update statement using Oracle ODP.Net in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, odp.net

I am using `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` to work with **Oracle** database in my **ASP.Net** application. There is no help documentation in **MSDN** for **ODP.Net** and **Oracle**'s documentation is really really bad. I am not able find the answer to this simple question.

Is it not possible to execute a simple update statement without having to build a `dataset` object and updating the `dataset`?

How to execute an update statement using **Oracle ODP.Net** in **C#**?

Comment: ODP.Net implements IDbCommand, IDbConnection and IDbDataAdapter why you cannot use them to prepare and execute your Update statement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I will need to check the exact syntax, but here is some quick code off the top of my head

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(...))
{
  con.Open();
  OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "update table set col1 = :param1, col2 = :param2 where key = :keyValue";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", 1);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "Text data");
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("keyValue", "1");
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The above creates a command object sets the command up to execute an SQL Update statement, in this example I show one way to setup a parameterized query, you should always go with a parameterized query. Once the command is setup you just call `ExecuteNonQuery` to actually execute the command.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you! Although I couldn't find "AddWithValue". ExecuteNonQuery was the key, i tried it with out a parameterized query and it worked. I think I can improvise it from here on. Really appreciate your time!!

Comment: Karthik, the advantage of using a parameterized query is that it does all the SQL injection protection for you.

Comment: Heya!
I'd only change a few things to add the transaction control that allows Oracle to perform update commands:

`code`
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
OracleTransaction oratrans = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
cmd.Transaction = oratrans;

.
.
.
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
oratrans.Commit();

Yours,

Answer (score 4):

So after a bit of sleuthing and working this one out for a while, I found that the method I used to add a new parameter to the connection command is as follows. I did not find the method as was stated in the previous post.  Mind you I am using a query object that I am passing the values around with.

```
  public Boolean InsertMethod(Query _query)
    {
        var success = false;
        var queryString = string.Format(@"INSERT INTO TABLE(ID, OWNER, TEXT) VALUES (TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:OWNER, :TEXT)");
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConString))
            {
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = queryString;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("OWNER", _query.Owner);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("TEXT", _query.Text);          

                int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsUpdated > 0) success = true;
            }

            return success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're inserting twice. two `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Chris's answer, here is the documentation page of [OracleParameter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/intro003.htm#BHCJFIAJ) class which has sample code on using [OracleCommand](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/OracleCommandClass.htm#i996876) to execute `Update`s.

EDIT: Here is the entry point for [ODP.net documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/toc.htm).

Comment: The link to the sample code you provided is talks about how to fetch data using OracleDataReader and not on how to update data (as per my initial question). I already went through the ODP.net documentation and I couldn't find a similar code sample for updating. I wish MSDN has documented this :(.