# insert data from public dataset into oracle table

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, insert, dataset

here's a sample of my code where i import data from excel and view in datagridview using a public dataset.
but when i try to imsert it into the oracle table RTGS_IMPORT, it does not give any error but does not import either :|
please help.. just an aspiring beginner :D

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string insqry = "INSERT INTO RTGS_IMPORT (BANK_ID,BANK,IFSC,BRANCHNAME,ADDRESS) VALUES (:BANK_ID,:BANK,:IFSC,:BRANCHNAME,:ADDRESS)";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=KBETEST;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbo;Password=dbo123;Unicode=True");
        conn.Open();
        OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
        OracleDataAdapter ad = new OracleDataAdapter();
        ad.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand(insqry, conn);

        foreach (DataRow drrow in ds.Tables["A"].Rows)
        { 

            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":BANK_ID", drrow["BANK_ID"]));
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":BANK", drrow["BANK NAME"]));
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":IFSC", drrow["IFSC"]));
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":BRANCHNAME", drrow["BRANCH NAME"]));
            ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":ADDRESS", drrow["ADDRESS"]));

        }
        conn.Dispose();


    }
```

Thanks in advance you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute the command after you set the parameters:

```
ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So:

```
foreach (DataRow drrow in ds.Tables["A"].Rows)
        { 
        ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":BANK_ID", drrow["BANK_ID"]));
        ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":BANK", drrow["BANK NAME"]));
        ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":IFSC", drrow["IFSC"]));
        ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":BRANCHNAME", drrow["BRANCH NAME"]));
        ad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":ADDRESS", drrow["ADDRESS"]));
        ad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Refer here: [Execute Update in C# and Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765962/how-to-execute-a-update-statement-using-oracle-odp-net-in-c-sharp)